# What is decl-reachable in C++ 20?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, c++-modules

[§10.4/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/module.global.frag) gives all the possible situations of decl-reachable in detail. However, I can't fully understand it. Consider the example described in [§10.4/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/module.global.frag):

```cpp
Source file "foo.h":
  namespace N {
  struct X {};
  int d();
  int e();
  inline int f(X, int = d()) { return e(); }
  int g(X);
  int h(X);
}

Module M interface:
module;
#include "foo.h"
export module M;
template<typename T> int use_f() {
  N::X x;                       // N​::​X, N, and ​::​ are decl-reachable from use_­f
  return f(x, 123);             // N​::​f is decl-reachable from use_­f,
                                // N​::​e is indirectly decl-reachable from use_­f
                                //   because it is decl-reachable from N​::​f, and
                                // N​::​d is decl-reachable from use_­f
                                //   because it is decl-reachable from N​::​f
                                //   even though it is not used in this call
}
template<typename T> int use_g() {
  N::X x;                       // N​::​X, N, and ​::​ are decl-reachable from use_­g
  return g((T(), x));           // N​::​g is not decl-reachable from use_­g
}
template<typename T> int use_h() {
  N::X x;                       // N​::​X, N, and ​::​ are decl-reachable from use_­h
  return h((T(), x));           // N​::​h is not decl-reachable from use_­h, but
                                // N​::​h is decl-reachable from use_­h<int>
}
int k = use_h<int>();
  // use_­h<int> is decl-reachable from k, so
  // N​::​h is decl-reachable from k

Module M implementation:
module M;
int a = use_f<int>();           // OK
int b = use_g<int>();           // error: no viable function for call to g;
                                // g is not decl-reachable from purview of
                                // module M's interface, so is discarded
int c = use_h<int>();           // OK
```

Why is `N​::​g` not decl-reachable from `use_­g`? Why is `N​::​h` not decl-reachable from `use_­h`, but `N​::​h` is decl-reachable from `use_­h<int>`? Why doesn't §10.4/(3.2) or §10.4/(3.3) apply to them?

Comment: A better question would be "what is the difference between `use_g` and `use_h` that makes them behave differently? That is, why is `g` not reachable from `use_g<int>`, but `h` is reachable from `use_h<int>`?  Because I can't see how they are in any way distinct.

Comment: @NicolBolas There is no difference between `use_g` and `use_h` as such, and `g` is reachable from `use_g<int>` The key difference is the presence of the declaration `int k = use_h<int>()`, which causes `use_h<int>` to be decl-reachable.

Comment: @NicolBolas Thanks for your suggestion.English is not my native language and sometimes I may not express my meaning exactly.I will pay attention to these problems.Thank you again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`N::f` is decl-reachable from `use_f` due to rule 10.4.3.2.

In determining whether `N::g` is reachable from `use_g`, we find that neither 10.4.3.2 nor 10.4.3.3 applies.

- 10.4.3.2 does not apply because `g((T(), x))` is a dependent call and thus, at the point of declaration of the template `use_g`, it can't be determined yet which function is actually named by the call. (It will be determined when `use_g` is instantiated, but in that case it may only imply that `N::g` is reachable from that particular specialization of `use_g`, not the template `use_g` itself.)
- 10.4.3.3 instructs us to consider a hypothetical call to `g` where each type-dependent argument is replaced by an expression of a type that has no associated namespaces or entities. Thus, for example, we could replace `(T(), x)` by `0`, giving the hypothetical call `g(0)`. This would not find `N::g` during the name lookup phase, so it doesn't make `N::g` decl-reachable.

For similar reasons, `N::h` is not decl-reachable from `use_h`.

When `use_h<int>` is instantiated, then rule 10.4.3.2 applies. At that point, the compiler determines that the type of `(T(), x)` is `N::X`, and actually performs the name lookup for `h`, finding `N::h` through argument-dependent lookup. That is, `h((T(), x))` names the function `N::h` in this particular specialization (where `T` = `int`), but not in the original template.